# St.spinner doesn't show (most times)

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a text area on a streamlit app where I ask a user to enter the query.

Once they do that and click Button or press enter, a function call is made to give a response.

To let a user know that the response is getting processed, I want to add a spinner.

However, in many cases I see spinner does't show on the app and only default "Running" on top right of Streamlit appears.

Here's the code I used for the same.

```
with st.container():
        query = st.text_area("**Ask a question here:**", height= 100, key= "query_text")
        button = st.button("Submit", key="button")
    if query:
        with st.spinner('Fetching Answer...'):
            response = custom_qa.qa.run(query)
            st.info(response.strip())
```

**Edit: Full code**

```
if uploaded_file is not None:
    display_pdf(uploaded_file)
    print(st.session_state.uploaded_file.name)
    if st.session_state.qa is None:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
            temp_file.write(uploaded_file.getvalue())
            temp_file_path = temp_file.name
            print(temp_file_path)
            st.session_state.qa = call_custom_qna(temp_file_path, model) # Passing the doc for chunking, indexing and retrieving

    print(f'QA Status Post Fn Call: {st.session_state.qa}')
    custom_qa = st.session_state.qa
    with st.container():
        query = st.text_area("**Ask a question here:**", height= 100, key= "query_text")
        button = st.button("Submit", key="button")
    if query:
         with st.spinner('Fetching Answer...'):
            response = custom_qa.qa.run(query)
            st.info(response.strip())
```

Comment: Is your code in a cache function?

Comment: no. see edit above

Comment: I added the edit above in case you missed it. Pls check the edit. Thanks

Comment: The spinner functions depending on the load time, in that case its visibility is random.